# Highlight multiple selected Table Data (<td></td>) in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

There is a lot of examples about select multiples row in ngRepeat, but what I need is highligth multiple Table Data  on click. This is what I have in my Controller:

```
    app.controller('CalendarCtrl', function($scope, Calendar){

    $scope.week = ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sab']

    $scope.hours = ['6:00','7:00','8:00','9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00','22:00','23:00'];


    $scope.idSelectedDayActive = null;
    $scope.idSelectedHourActive = null;
    $scope.setSelected = function (day, hour) {

        $scope.idSelectedDayActive = day;
        $scope.idSelectedHourActive = hour;

    };
```

This is my View

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th scope="col" title="Monday"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
    <th ng-repeat="d in week" scope="col">{{d}}</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="h in hours">
      <td class="col">{{h}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="d in week"  
          ng-click="setSelected(d, h)"
          ng-class="{'calendar-element-active' : d === idSelectedDayActive && h === idSelectedHourActive, 'calendar-element-disable' : d === idSelectedDayDisable && h === idSelectedHourDisable}">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This are my CSS classes:

```
    .table tbody>tr>td.calendar-element-active, .table tbody>tr>td.calendar-element-active {
        background-color: #00d0d1;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    .table tbody>tr>td.calendar-element-disable {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

And a Plunker [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jOfo1Me1OM6PUWHAtvN6)

Comment: sorry...i idint understand this "highligth multiple Table Data on click"??will u please explain this

Comment: When user click on table row data (cell), need to change the background, see the DEMO for an example and click on a table cell (like Excel table) and see how the background color change, but if you click another cell, the last clicked cell background color disappear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You can do it like this, The Js

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('CalendarCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.week = ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sab']

    $scope.hours = ['6:00','7:00','8:00','9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00','22:00','23:00'];


    $scope.idSelectedDayActive = null;
    $scope.idSelectedHourActive = null;
    $scope.selectedCells = [];
    $scope.setSelected = function (day, hour) {
       for(let selectedCell in $scope.selectedCells){
           if($scope.selectedCells[selectedCell].day == day && 
              $scope.selectedCells[selectedCell].hour == hour){ 
               $scope.selectedCells.splice(selectedCell,1);
               return ;
           }
        }
        $scope.selectedCells.push({'day':day,'hour':hour});
   };    
  $scope.check = function(day,hour){
    for(let selectedCell of $scope.selectedCells){
      if(selectedCell.day == day && selectedCell.hour == hour)
       return true
    }
    return false
  }  


});
```

And in Html

```
<tr ng-repeat="h in hours">
   <td class="col">{{h}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="d in week"  ng-click="setSelected(d, h)"ng-class="{'calendar-element-active' : check(d,h), 'calendar-element-disable' : d === idSelectedDayDisable && h === idSelectedHourDisable}">
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Basically it is your logic only, just instead of a single selected, you have to use array and make it array of selected cells

Edit :- For removing the selected item, the setselected function is just checking if the cell is currently selected.. if it selected then it deselects and returns if the loop goes through without returning a new cell is selected

Comment: How I can disable selected array?

Comment: Updated the answer. @CristianEcheverria

Comment: Wait what you want when disabled? what is the scenario for that?

Comment: Just put the background white, without color, and delete the selectedCell from the selectedCells array

Comment: Imagine if I select an array of selectedCells, but later want to disable one or many selectedCells by just clicking on them again and put the background color of each disable cells white and delete them from the selectedCells array. Thanks for your time!!

Comment: I believe it does what you want in the updated answer